# python requests stream iterate header only instead of body

Tags: python, request, stream

This code I got from this [site](https://medium.com/edureka/python-requests-tutorial-30edabfa6a1c)

```
import requests
req = requests.get('path/to/forest.jpg', stream=True)
req.raise_for_status()
with open('Forest.jpg', 'wb') as fd:
  for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=50000):
    print('Received a Chunk')
    fd.write(chunk)
```

Basically that code explains how to get the body content streamly. My case is similiar. Instead of iterating the body content, I just want to iterate the **http header**. Specifically, I just want to get `Set-Cookie` header and then terminate the connection. With doing that, I can save my download bandwidth if the body content is large while I just need the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `response.headers` to only get HTTP headers:

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com", stream=True)
print(resp.headers["Set-Cookie"])
```

Prints:

```
SOCS=ABBaBgiFrKdpBg; expires=Tue, 12-Nov-2024 10:43:27 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; ...
```